# Difference between pulling from center of mass, and from the top of a wheel

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, work, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

> A homogeneous cylinder with radius $R$ and mass $M$ is pulled with constant horizontal force $F$ across a table. There are two cases, one where the cylinder is pulled from its center of mass and one where the cylinder is pulled from the top.
>
> [image]
>
> What is the angular velocity of the cylinder, when the cylinder's **center of mass** has moved the distance $L$, in both cases?

### Attempt

The gain in kinetic energy: $\Delta E_{kin}=\frac{1}{2}Mv^2+\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$

Because it is a cylinder, $I=\frac{1}{2}MR^2$. Because the cylinder is rolling $v = R\omega$.

$\Delta E_{kin} = \frac{1}{2}MR^2\omega^2 + \frac{1}{4}MR^2\omega^2 = \frac{3}{4}MR^2\omega^2$.

The work theorem says $\Delta E_{kin}=FL$ and we can isolate $\omega$ in the equation.

$\omega = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{FL}{MR^2}}$

This was the case when it was pulled from its center of mass, but what about when the cylinder is pulled from the top? Is there even a difference, and if so, how would one even recognize the difference? To me, it is not obvious at all what difference it would make to pull the cylinder at the top instead of its center.

Comment: Is the cylinder in pure rolling only?

Comment: @JAlex It is not stated in the problem, but I'm very sure that it is pure rolling.

Comment: @carl i answered your question, please give me feedback

Comment: This is a fun experiment to do with a yo-yo.  In this setup, you can vary the *angle* of the applied force: if you pull straight up, the yo-yo unrolls the string & travels away from you. If you pull horizontally, the yo-yo rolls up towards you. In between, there's a calculatable angle at which the yo-yo slides without rolling!

Comment: The cylinder cannot roll if you pull horizontally thru the center of mass, unless you allow for some sort of infinitesimal axle rather than pulling from a connection point on the surface.  The problem is ill-stated.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft With friction between the cylinder and the ground and no slipping then pulling at the centre of mass will produce rotation as well as translation - think of pulling a bicycle.   If there was no friction then there would be slipping and no rotation of the cylinder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

First case you have:

$$T=\frac 12 M\,v^2+\frac 12 I\omega^2=F\,L$$
with :
$$v=\omega\,R~,I=\frac 12 M\,R^2$$

you obtain

$$ \omega=\frac{2}{3}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{R}\,\sqrt{\frac{F\,L}{M}}$$

second case

$$T=\frac 12 M\,v^2+\frac 12 I\omega^2=F\,L+F\,R\,\varphi$$

with
$$\varphi=\frac{x}{R}=\frac{L}{R} \,,v=\omega\,R$$

you obtain

$$ \omega=\frac{2}{3}\frac{\sqrt{6}}{R}\,\sqrt{\frac{F\,L}{M}}$$

with:

Comment: How did you equate $\varphi = \frac{L}{R}$. Where does this relationship come from?

Comment: with $~v=\omega\,R~,\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\,R$ or $~x=\varphi\,R~$ with $~x=L~$ you get it